# SSIS: Sequence container counts Warnings as Errors

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools

I'm debugging an SSIS package that I've just developed.
I've found the package failed because a sequence container is Red though all the tasks on it are green. I checked the process results and found there were 4 Warinigs *(=exclamations)* and no fatal errors. I want to have the container ignore Warnings and counts only fatal errors. Could anyone let me know how?

Comment: What are the errors and warning? please provide more informations

Comment: warnings can lead to errors while executing the package. you have to read this warnings and try to fix them

Comment: Thanks for the comments! In the package, I have a File System Task to create a directory with its UseDirectoryIfExists property = True. When a folder exists, it fires warning though that's just what I expects.

Comment: From the package execution log. What is the error?

Comment: Everyone, I'm sorry I've found that this question was based on my misunderstanding on the situation. There was a task hidden behind another task, which caused the validation (not run time) error and made the container fail.